# Regex expression to allow only characters used for writing articles

Tags: php, regex

I am looking to construct a regex expression that allows charachters that are used for writing articles, such as:

- Alphabets: a-zA-Z
- Numbers: 0-9
- Special characters: -.,+*/'´"!#%&/()=?@£$€{[]}_:;
- Spaces: newlines(enter space) and spaces

My inital attempt using php, looked like this:

```
 preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z,0-9],.;+- /', ,'', $input)
```

But the line above didn't work

Edit: second attempt to escape the characters to avoid messing up the expression:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z,0-9]\-\.\,\+\*\/\'\´\"\!\#\%\&\/\(\)\=\?\@\£\$\€\{\[\]\}\_\:\;/', '', $input)
```

Comment: Use regex 101 for creating regex it has a handy tool that shows you what matches what, you will also receive a complete explanation of all the tokens etc

Comment: The real question is why do you want to have a control on characters used in articles? Without context it looks like a crazy idea!

Comment: @sln I mean to say that you can see in real time what your regular expressions matchup to and also have a cheat sheet of all the tokens used in regex, I never said that regex101 teaches you regex, I said it's a handy tool to help you with problematic regex problems, much better than saving your code then refreshing a page again and again in order to see if it works

Comment: @ImmortalDude - Yeah, I see, well what if you don't have the internet. How is that tool going to teach you regex ? Does it offer you suggestions or substitute constructs to use when writing a regex ?

Comment: @sln `ctrl + s` my friend, or a website downloader, and again regex 101 is not to teach, you must know regex in the first place in order for the site to be of any use, it's to help (emphasis on the word help) you with regex

Comment: So run the mht of the regex101 site locally ? I'll give that a try, will let you know how much it taught me about regular expression nuance.

Comment: Btw, I use regexformat9 app. Makes regex101 look like kindergarten.

Comment: @sln a simple Ctrl + s will suffice , but then again your point of regex 101 not being able to teach is perfectly valid and hence I say regex 101 is a tool to help you not teach you, you have to know what regexe are and how to construct them in order for the site to help you at all, else you're just poking in the dark hoping that you hit a light switch

Comment: @sln to each his own tools, i like regex101 you like regexformat9 , you should suggest nice tools like these , I'll give it a try for sure on Monday and who knows I may even switch to it , cheers :)

Comment: Yeah, uising that app, I didn't know regex 2 years ago, now I'm an expert

Comment: @sln, well yeah it has, regexes are tested validated and even long matching  / dead end regexes are validated , it shows you the problem too, give it a try, maybe you'll like it? Never say no until you've tried it :)

Comment: @ImmortalDude - I try to avoid making regex101 links since nothing is permafrost, but only to show a quick link to an already explained regex solution. In other words, I got tired of flunky's saying it doesn't work. I develop the solution totally on regexformat9 app.

Comment: @sln fair enough, a valid statement

Answer (score 2):

The `preg_replace` function expects three parameters, not two. A regex, the replacement value, and then the string it should match against.

Additionally your regex should have all characters in the character class, otherwise you are matching that character class then the literal characters after it which likely don't occur. The `;+` also would allow for multiple continuous semicolons, not a `+` because it is a quantifier when not in a character class and unescaped.

```
 preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9,.;+-]+/', '', $input)
```

another regex you could potentially use would be:

```
preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]+/u', '', $input)
```

this will replace any non

> Visible characters and spaces (anything except control characters)

you can read more here https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: Regarding the missing paramter in the preg_replace function, that is correct, it was a typo when drafting up the post.

`'/[^[:print:]]+/u'` is a good start, but its kinda to wide, as it allows to use åöä, and it also removes newlines (enter space), which i wish to keep. I accidentally left out that requirement, will add it now to the post

Comment: And i also tried to escape the characters to avoid messing up the expression, but still didnt work. You can see the attempt in the post above.

Comment: @pabloBar You can just use the first regex and add characters you want to allow, a whitelist if you will. I don't see why you wouldn't allow UTF8 alpha characters in your articles though. `åöä` could be part of someone's name and you now potentially will be removing them.

Comment: @sln I know, I expected those to be valid characters for an article. Unclear what an article should be containing I guess, maybe just ASCII.